# ¿Qué son las "aguas mayores"?

Tags: significado

En estos momento estoy leyendo un libro y en él encuentro la palabra 
**aguas mayores**:

> su propia hija, que por indiscreción había visto sus **aguas mayores** en el dormitorio, contestara que de verdad la bacinilla era de mucho oro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Aguas mayores* quiere decir excrementos:

> [**agua**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1BKpQj3)
>
> **aguas mayores**
>   1. f. pl. Excremento humano.
>   2. f. pl. Mar. Las más grandes mareas de los equinoccios.

De la misma manera que las *menores* son las orinas:

> **aguas menores**
>   1. f. pl. Orina humana.
>   2. f. pl. Mar. Mareas diarias o comunes.

Es muy raro oír esta expresión en el habla cotidiana, incluso en la culta. No deja de ser una forma muy fina de hablar para un concepto que tiene mil y una variantes, no tan finas pero igualmente púdicas. Yo la he visto sobre todo para decir *que se va a hacer X*: *voy a hacer aguas mayores/menores*. Para calificar la orina o el excremento no lo había leído nunca.

En general, para ser fino uno puede decir:

> Voy al baño / servicio.

Comment: Gracias, eso veo ya que la conversación es entre una hija de un rey y una persona cualquiera.

Comment: te ganaste un +1 por responder acerca de hacer del "2" :-)  Nunca había visto esta expresión....interesante

Comment: @DGaleano, se dice "hacer el uno / hacer el dos" en en Colombia? En inglés se dice "number one and number two" para lo que son aguas menores/mayores, pero pensaba que nadie usaba un equivalente literal en español.

Comment: @Diego No es que se use mucho, pero los doblajes de la TV lo han popularizado y ya la gente lo entiende. Por lo general tendemos a no dar muchos detalles de la actividad a realizar o realizada y como dice fedorqui decimos "voy al baño"

Comment: @Diego Aquí decimos "lo primero" y "lo segundo" para "number one" y "numer two".

Comment: En México es muy común este par de eufemismos, sobre todo hablando con los niños.  Si tu hijo entra al baño y quieres saber si va a necesitar ayuda, preguntas, "¿Vas a hacer del dos?"  // Hay que explicar a Dacoso que "mayor" no sólo significa "más grande," sino también más importante.  También hay que explicar que las "aguas negras" son los desechos humanos, que antaño (y todavía hoy día en lugares pobres e insalubrios) se dejaban ir al río o al canal.

Comment: @DGaleano volví a esta pregunta por casualidad ¿te parece que formule una pregunta genérica sobre lo de "hacer del 2" y ver cómo se dice según el país?

Comment: @Diego ^ lo que le comento a DGaleano. Creo que no tenemos pregunta así en el sitio

Comment: @Gustavson ^ lo que comento a DGaleano. Veo que cada país tiene sus variantes